# jQuery Mobile radio buttons use fieldset and legend

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-fieldset, jquery-mobile-radio

[The documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-forms.html) uses a fieldset with a legend to tell the user what to do.
But I would like to use the full width of the screen.

If I remove the legend, then there is a blank column on the right-hand side now instead of the left.

Q: How can I use the entire width of the screen when asking for radio button input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/e3Z6w/

This css override will fix your problem. It works on **`radio button`** and **`checkboxes`**.

```
.ui-controlgroup-label {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gajotres!  ui-controlgroup-label didn't work for me, but .ui-field-contain .ui-controlgroup-controls {} did work.

Comment: How so? It is working in an example. Your solution has a problem, while label is indeed 100% of a page label text is still 20% of a available page. This example is made in jQuery Mobile 1.3.1